# Laravel - Server can't set cache

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm currently setting a lot of settings from my `settings` table, in my local server everything is fine, but the problem is in the online environment, I don't know if I need to configure anything, but it is not setting the cache, what can it be?

```
class SettingsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(Factory $cache, SettingRepository $settings)
    {
        if(Schema::hasTable('settings')){
            $settings = $cache->remember('settings', 60, function() use ($settings)
            {
                return $settings->lists();
            });
            config()->set('settings', $settings);
        }
    }
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            \App\Repositories\SettingRepository::class
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your cache driver, and is it installed on the production environment?

Comment: @MinaAbadir I don't know, I just installed lamp in both environments, but in the production it won't work

Comment: What is your cache driver? Did you configure the cache in the new .env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`composer clear-cache` && `composer dump-autoload` solved the problem